# Is "montäglich" commonly used?

Tags: word-usage

Both *Duden Universalwörterbuch* and *Wahrig Deutsches Wörterbuch* contain the word "montäglich", meaning "happening regularly on Mondays".

But my German professor says he has never heard of this word. He would simply use the word "Montags".

Is "montäglich" just a rare alternative for "Montags"? What about "mittwöchlich"? It is accepted by *Wahrig* but not *Duden*.

Comment: *montäglich* is by far now my new favourite word :p

Comment: To express the regularity, you could also say "findet an mehreren Montagen statt" oder "findet jeden Montag statt".

Comment: @gented Naaah... my favorite word is clearly *sonntäglich.* So many nice activities come to mind which can be combined with *sonntäglich* -- after *ausschlafen* a *brunch*, followed by a *Frühschoppen*, a *Spaziergang*, then *Kaffee und Kuchen*,  topping it off with a *Braten* -- the *Sonntagsbraten*. None of these combine as well with Monday: On any given Monday there is either no time or no money for it ;-).

Comment: The interesting part of this word is that it is extremely rarely used, but I strongly assume that any native german speaker would understand its meaning immediately (even if they never have heard that word before).

Comment: Tl;dr It is used, but not commonly and mostly in texts, not speech.

Comment: @gented It's a good idea to borrow that into English, thus saying "Mondaily" ("Sundaily" etc.)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since *montags* is an adverb and *montäglich* an adjective, they cannot simply be alternatives for each other. In fact, *montäglich* is only rarely used adverbially.

> Die Rufe nach „Widerstand“ […] hallen seit nunmehr fast einem Jahr montäglich durch die Straßen der Dresdner Altstadt. ([1](https://www.mainpost.de/ueberregional/politik/zeitgeschehen/Ermittlungen-gegen-Pegida-Demo-Teilnehmer-wegen-Galgen-Attrappe;art16698,8955997))

Most of the time, is used attributively.

> Ob in der S-Bahn, an der Kasse des neuen Supermarktes oder beim montäglichen Friedensgebet in der Nikolaikirche, überall ist diese Frage derzeit zu hören. ([2](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22Nur+losziehen+und+zuschlagen%22+site%3Azeit.de))
>
> Und das betrifft nicht nur den Prüfauftrag für die Streichung der montäglichen Briefzustellung. ([3](https://www.general-anzeiger-bonn.de/news/wirtschaft/regional/viel-zuendstoff_aid-44783741))

Interestingly, and in opposition to the dictionary definition, *montäglich* is used to refer to a single monday in the following article (this might also be the case for [7](https://www.stuttgarter-nachrichten.de/inhalt.trollinger-dance-contest-tanz-im-wengert.497fc4e1-e3c2-43a6-a62d-5b3217388ea5.html) below).

> Trotz Kälte und früher Uhrzeit lohnt sich das Aufstehen: Der montägliche "Super-Blutmond" bietet nämlich die letzte Chance für fast zehn Jahre, hierzulande eine totale Verfinsterung des Mondes zur Gänze zu sehen.  ([4](https://www.derstandard.at/story/2000096343865/montagfrueh-gibt-es-einen-super-blutmond))

As far as Wednesday is concerned, I'd say that words such as *mittwöchlich* or *mittwöchentlich* are *Gelegenheitsbildungen* (eng. *nonce words*; [5](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelegenheitsbildung), [6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word)): words that are created occasionally but have not entered common use. The fact that there are two competing forms seems to support this. Two examples:

> Die Choreographie hat Sabine Berner beim mittwöchentlichen Training auf den Titel „Trollinger on the Rockz“ einstudiert, der 2014 beim ersten Trollinger Song Contest Platz zwei belegte. ([7](https://www.stuttgarter-nachrichten.de/inhalt.trollinger-dance-contest-tanz-im-wengert.497fc4e1-e3c2-43a6-a62d-5b3217388ea5.html))
>
> Allein der mittwöchliche Pendelverkehr von der Stettener Festhalle und vom Weiher zum Marktplatz wird wohl für drei Monate kostenlos sein […] ([8](https://www.schwarzwaelder-bote.de/inhalt.hechingen-diskussion-ueber-kostenlose-fahrten.5eef2f0a-885e-4de4-8b1b-c6a8400ba050.html))

Comment: Good analysis and research, including the exceptions (adverbial use and use for a single Monday).

Comment: Very good indeed. One might add that most Germans will understand these created words (be it any of the two variants for mittwoch given in the last paragraphs)

Comment: _montäglich is used to refer to a single monday_ yes, but imo this is wrong.

Comment: Let me guess, you're from Saxony, David? :)

Comment: Also, I agree with TaW: the third example's author is using "montägliche" erroneously. It needs to be "Der am Montag sichtbare" or whatever. But "montägliche" would mean that there's a blood moon each Monday.

Comment: The second-to-last-example (7; "beim mittwöchentlichen Training") seems to be a differently motivated neologism. It could be literally translated as "always occurring in the middle of the week". I quite like that word, too!

Comment: "montäglich is used to refer to a single monday" - for this, there is _montägig_ - https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/montaegig

Comment: @JoeStevens That is even rarer than *montäglich*. A quick search suggests it might be in use in Austria.

Answer (score 17):

*Montäglich* is indeed a **very** rare alternative for *montags*, and most people would say

> Die Veranstaltung findet montags statt

and *not*

> Die Veranstaltung findet montäglich statt.

There is however a construction where you could not use the more common word.
If you say

> Unser montägliches Treffen findet diese Woche eine Stunde früher statt

the alternatives would be either

> Unser Montags-Treffen findet diese Woche eine Stunde früher statt

if you have more than one meeting each week,
or

> Unser wöchentliches Treffen findet diese Woche eine Stunde früher statt

if there is only one weekly meeting.

In this case I would slightly prefer the version with *montäglich*.

Comment: absolutely right. I clicked here because I understand the word without recalling I ever heard it. But "unser montägliches Treffen..." would sound normal to me.

Comment: "Die Veranstaltung findet montags statt" bedeutet für mich nicht, dass sie regelmäßig montags stattfindet, im Ggs. zu "montäglich".

Comment: Wer "montags" korrekt verwendet, meint allerdings sehr wohl "jeden Montag".

Comment: I think "montägliche Veranstaltung" is used where "montagsne Veranstaltung" would sound too wrong.

Comment: Montäglich nutze ich nicht, aber der "sonntäglichen Spaziergang  zur Kirche" ist bei uns zuhause gebräuchlich.

Comment: @rvf Eine Veranstaltung, die immer am ersten Montag des jeweiligen Monats stattfindet, findet auch *montags* statt

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Nein, siehe [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/montags).

Answer (score 5):

For real data of German word usage there is the Wortschatz portal at Leipzig University. The [query for *montäglich*](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl-public_2018&word=mont%C3%A4glich) gives as of today an indication of its frequency (class 22, which translates to "extremely rare" according to the [FAQ](https://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/de/documentation/faq#corporaportal_wordinformation)) and some usage samples.

EDIT: The Wortschatz portal discriminates by word form, so [*montägliche*](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl-public_2018&word=mont%C3%A4gliche) is counted as a different word (frequency class 20). The word form *mittwöchlich* is not found in the corpus, [*mittwöchliche*](https://corpora.uni-leipzig.de/de/res?corpusId=deu_newscrawl-public_2018&word=mittw%C3%B6chliche) has frequency class 23.

Comment: It is a pity they only count word forms and not lexemes. The most frequent ending seems to be *-en*, giving *montäglichen* a frequency class of 18. The form *sonntäglichen* has frequency class 15, probably because of the obvious shift in meaning (from *every Sunday* to *characteristic for a Sunday*). However rare these words may be, their morphological transparency ensures that they are understood (which is what distinguishes them from a form such as *eskamotiert*, frequency class 22).

Comment: I feel a little bit offended that _eskamotiert_ has the same frequency class as _montäglich_.

Comment: @kap So we should discuss this word until it goes away?

Comment: Wenn die Schüler weiterhin jeden Freitag für die Zukunft demonstrieren, wird sich hierfür das Adjektiv "freitäglich" gelegentlich zeigen. Obwohl "Freitags-Demo" sicher der normale Ausdruck bleiben wird. Ich denke das war ein Grund für die Hervorhebung des "montäglich" über z.B. "dienstäglich". Sonntag war hier im christlichen D A CH immer ein besonderer Tag, daher zeigt sich das auch im nicht ganz so seltenen "sonntäglich".